# Dart: Errors while performing "pub get" and "pub build"

Tags: build, dart

We have an automated DART build by running a script that navigates to the project folder (where .yaml file is located) and runs "pub get" and "pub build". It was working for a while, but now we are getting this (in both cases):

```
Unhandled exception:
Illegal argument(s): join(null, "Pub", "Cache"): part 0 was null, but part 1 was not.
#0      _validateArgList (package:path/src/context.dart:497)
#1      Context.join (package:path/src/context.dart:187)
#2      join (package:path/path.dart:235)
#3      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-stable/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:69)
#4      _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:214)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:124)
```

What could be the reason for this? We use SDK 1.4.0.

Thank you,

Yuri.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run it manually?

Comment: I have more or less the same setup copy on my local server and I do not have this problem. I cannot run it manually on the company build server.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Eviroment variable 'APPDATA' on `AppData\Roaming`

and also set `PUB_CACHE` to a folder where you want the well pub cache